# Read Shared Documents from Sharepoint 2010 in .Net Framework 4.0 application

Tags: sharepoint, .net-4.0, sharepoint-2010

**I have to read Shared Documents from all sites/subsites of Sharepoint in my Console application which will run on the same machine where Sharepoint is installed but it will be based on .Net Framework 4.0**. I believe, Sharepoint Server Objects is based on Framework 3.5 so I came up with idea to create my custom web service which read and return list of documents.
I created my custom Service as mentiond in [this blog](http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html) and it is working fine. Here is my code to read the documents in one of my web service method.

```
SPWebApplication webApp = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
            #region Traverse all sub sites
            foreach (SPSite subSite in webApp.Sites)
            {
                using (SPWeb sWeb = subSite.OpenWeb())
                {
            foreach (SPList list in sWeb.Lists)
            {
                if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary &&
                                    list.Hidden == false && list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary &&
                                    list.Title.Equals("Style Library", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == false &&
                                    list.Title.Equals("Site Assets", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == false)
```

But as soon as I reach on following line "**foreach (SPList list in sWeb.Lists)**" it throw exception of type "**'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'**"

Even if I try to get the Lists count above this foreach loop **sWeb.Lists.count**, it still throw the same exception.
Please help me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: doesn't the out-of-the-box web services do what you want ?

Comment: Also, you should ask on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Steve, what do you mean by "out-of-the-bod web services"? You mean the services which is builten in Sharepoint foundation?

Comment: How can I access all subsites by giving root site URL using this service. Please note that I need to read docuements from all sites/subsites. I will appreciate if you can give me any idea or sample code.

Comment: this may help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcwebs.webs.getwebcollection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [SharePoint Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx).  It provides an easy way to call SharePoint web services.  Using the Server Object Model in a client application is tricky and does not provide a good authentication technique.  I believe your problem is with authentication since you cannot setup credentials for the Server Object Model.